# How to access all list elements from last to first in python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 1000 elements. How do I access all of them starting from last element to the first one in a loop.

```
list = [4,3,2,1]
for item in list:
    print(from last to first)
```

output = [1,2,3,4]

Comment: `for i in list_[::-1]:`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Try:**

```
list = [4,3,2,1]

print [x for x in list[::-1]]
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = [4,3,2,1]

print [i for i in list[::-1]]
```

Which gives the desired [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Nice answer, same as mine.

Comment: Ah, you just beat me to it!